# How can I change the level of the References in the Table of Contents by using the package "bibunits" for long monographs

Tags: table-of-contents, subdividing, bibunits

In monographs, references are often put at the end of each chapter, and the **bibunits** package can be used. References in the Table of Contents(ToC) should have the same level as section as follows:

```
CONTENTS...................1
1 XX.......................3
    1.1 XX ................3
    1.2 XX ................4
    References.............6
2 XX.......................7
    2.1 XX ................7

... ...
```

(correct ToC above)

However, I get the following ToC where References appear as chapter level.

```
CONTENTS...................1
1 XX.......................3
    1.1 XX ................3
    1.2 XX ................4
References.................6
2 XX.......................7
    2.1 XX ................7

... ...
```

(incorrect ToC above)

Here are my codes.

```
\documentclass{book}
...
\usepackage[sectionbib]{bibunits}
...
\begin{document}
...
\bibliographyunit[\chapter]
...
\chapter{XX}
\section{XX}
...
\putbib
...
\chapter{XX}
...
\end{document}
```

How can I get the correct ToC.

Any response would be appreciated.

--

Best wishes,

radiofeda

Comment: by default you do not get an entry in the toc. Do you have a command like `\addcontentsline....`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me. I think you need to provide a more complete example.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{asdf, author={TH.}, title={Foo Bar}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{bibunits}
\defaultbibliography{\jobname}
\defaultbibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\bibliographyunit[\chapter]
\tableofcontents
\chapter{XX}
\section{XX}
\nocite{asdf}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bibname}
\putbib
...
\chapter{XX}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?  I did as above and now have my references listed as  section but also underneath as a chapter.

Comment: @Rachel: Welcome to tex.sx! Your question won't be seen by many people here so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. Follow-up questions like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

Comment: @Rachel: I converted your post to a comment. Please add comments (like this one; this however requires 50rep) or post a follow-up question like Hendrik suggested. Answers are for actual solutions only. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference of experience here:  the original poster sees References shown as Chapter level headings in the ToC, while TH sees nothing until a `\addcontentsline` command is added.  I have the same behaviour as the OP and think, after some experimentation, that it is due to the use of the Springer version of the book document class by the OP and me.  If the book class is used, the chapter heading disappears from the ToC, or if `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bibname}` is included in the source file, the heading is displayed as a section heading, but as 'Bibliography'.

So I conclude that there is an interaction between bibunits and the Springer monograph document class, svmono (downloadable from http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/svmono.zip ), but I haven't been able to locate how to eliminate the interaction and, especially, how to remove the redundant References chapter heading in the ToC.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out the three following lines in `svmono.cls`:

```
 ..

\DeclareOption{sectrefs}{\let\secbibl=Y}

..


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\refname}%

..

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}%
```

Doing this, I did manage to get the references at the level I actually want.

Comment: This should be a comment to Nigel's answer.

Comment: @lockstep I disagree. Nigel's "answer" is a guess about where the problem might lie.  This is a concrete attempt to provide a solution.  An accompanying minimal document would be useful to check that it actually works...